# Does it pay to store instant coffee in the freezer?

Tags: coffee

I understand that it pays to store freshly ground coffee in the freezer. What about instant coffee or cheep prepacked Turkish coffee?

Comment: Your understanding remains an item of debate. The coffee stack would be a better place for the question. And you can't preserve quality that's not there to start with.

Comment: See [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/99) on the (non-?)benefits of freezing coffee, over at [coffee.se] SE! We have several questions about storage, instant coffee, etc., that are related and might be helpful.

Comment: If you'd like to leave the question here, I'll answer it with some answers and links to [coffee.se]. If you'd like to delete this question and move it to [coffee.se], we'll answer it there!

Comment: I didn't realize there was a coffee stack exchange. I feel OK leaving this here because the question has more to do with food storage than coffee.

Answer (score 2):

In chemistry it is generally accepted that a reaction rate drops in half for each 10 degrees in C drop (about 20 degrees Fahrenheit). So oxygen would still oxidize the freeze dried coffee, but at a slower rate.

Comment: Is the only issue oxidation?

Answer (score 2):

It's ok to store freshly grounded coffee or instant coffee in a freezer. Just consider to:

- Pack the coffee in a sealed package or container.
- Avoid keeping coffee with some other high fragrances items such as vanilla essence, rose water etc as these things can affect the main coffee essence.

Here is a source on [How to Store coffee](http://www.friedcoffee.com/how-to-store-coffee-at-home/) that has a clear explanation.